# LPTHW Python text adventure game - issue with loading another location

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I am missing something. I have put together several modules and I tried debugging it but I still can't find a reason why it does not work.
There is module **start.py** which jumpstarts the whole game - there is no bug there, after you create character it loads a module **game.py** which controls the position of player and also lists all location available in the game. Locations are separated in individual modules, in this case I have only two of the so far: **apartment.py** and **curling_street.py**.

My module **apartment.py** works just fine but when it returns the string *'curling street'* which should load **curling_street.py** it writes out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 56, in <module>
     splash_screen()
  File "start.py", line 39, in splash_screen
     a_game.move()
  File "/Volumes/DATA HD/Dropbox/Python/ex45/game.py", line 18, in move
    get_next_map = current_map.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

I believe my *Engine* class is not written correctly. Here are the modules.

### start.py

```
import sys
import custom_error
import player
import handler
import prompt
import game


def splash_screen():
    print chr(27) + "[2J"
    print "*" * 80
    print "***** Welcome to ZOMBIE ADVENTURE *****"
    print "*" * 80
    print "\nSelect option:"
    print "1. Start a new game"
    print "2. Load existing game"
    print "3. Quit"

    while True:
        action = prompt.menu()

        if action == 1:
            create_player = player.CreateNewPlayer()
            new_player = player.Player(create_player.name, create_player.age, create_player.male, create_player.inventory)

            print "\nYour name is %s and you're %d old." % (new_player.name, new_player.age)
            print "It is %s that you're a man." % new_player.male

            print "\n1. Continue to game"
            print "2. Back to main menu"
            action = prompt.menu()

            while True:
                if action == 1:
                    game.Engine.launchgame()
                elif action == 2:
                    exit(1)
                else:
                    custom_error.error(1)
                    # a_game = game.Engine('Room1')
                    # a_game.LaunchGame(new_player)
        elif action == 2:
             handler.load()
        elif action == 3:
             exit(1)
        else:
             custom_error.errortype(0)

splash_screen()
```

### game.py

```
import apartment
import curling_street


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, the_player, start_map):
        self.the_player = the_player
        self.start_map = start_map

    def move(self):

        current_map = Maps.map_dict.get(self.start_map)
        print "Now entering %s." % current_map
        raw_input(">")

        while True:
            get_next_map = current_map.enter()
            current_map = Maps.map_dict.get(get_next_map)


class Maps(object):

    map_dict = {
    'apartment': apartment,
    'curling street': curling_street
    }

    def visited(self):
        visited_maps = map_dict.keys()
```

### apartment.py

```
 def enter():
    print "Apartment location"
    raw_input("now going to curling street")
    return 'curling street'
```

### curling_street.py

```
def enter():
    print "Curling Street location"
```

Comment: Could you please review your code - the line in the traceback `a_game.move()` is not currently in `splash_screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's when entering "curling street" and not after that? Your curling_street `enter` function doesn't return anything, so the next iteration through the loop, it will be accessing the dict with a `None` key, which will probably return a `None` object, which has no `enter` member. Looks like you need:

1. A return value from `curling_street.enter`
2. A way to exit the loop in the game engine.

Comment: thank you that didn't occcur to me. I put `import sys` and `exit(1)` in the `enter` function and now it works.

Comment: @user3056783 I think it would make more sense to hand back to the main game loop to exit (or allow the user to restart, etc) - for a start, this makes it easier to change the order of locations, add new ones, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
current_map = Maps.map_dict.get(get_next_map)
```

to access the maps from the dictionary. However, if there is no key `get_next_map` in the dictionary, `dict.get()` will `return None` instead. Currently, `curling_street.enter` will `return None`, which is not a key in the dictionary, hence the `current_map  is None` and you get an error. You should check for this end game state:

```
while True:
    get_next_map = current_map.enter()
    current_map = Maps.map_dict.get(get_next_map)
    if current_map is None:
        break
```